# Number of operation while considering time complexity of a algorithm

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

While calculating time complexity of a algorithm of finding maximum number of a sequence n,total number of operation is 2(n-1)+1..I can understand it but it does not make sense to me why aren't we considering assigning temporary maximum to the variable as a operation?

Comment: Question is not clear. Do you have any code for the calculation ?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Assignments take constant time, O(n) = 2(n-1)+1+C, which then can be dropped because it is negligible compared to other parts of the computation.

Comment: Okay..thanks for clearing the doubt

Comment: Answer is not fully correct. Every assignment takes constant time, but n assignments take time proportional to n (while this fact does not change overall asymptotic)